# Ever since + past tense + , + present progressive

Tags: tense, clauses

Okay, so I know that traditionally it would be proper to say:

- *Ever since Nina **moved** to Nebraska, she **has had** a lot of problems with allergies.*

But is it ungrammatical to say the following:

- *Ever since Nina **moved** to Nebraska, she **is having** a lot of problems with allergies.*

Comment: The present perfect brings up the past action with results in the present; *since* talks about *from a point in the past up to the present.*

Answer (score 2):

> Ever since Nina moved to Nebraska, she has had a lot of problems with
>   allergies.
>
> Ever since Nina moved to Nebraska, she has been having a lot of
>   problems with allergies.
>
> Ever since Nina moved to Nebraska, she is having a lot of problems
>   with allergies.

Starting with the point in time when Nina became a Nebraskan...

... she has had problems with allergies

... she has been having problems with allergies

*... she is having problems with allergies*

The last one should be replaced with the second one, **has been having**.

In typical conversation, it would be:

... *she's* been having

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the second example is ungrammatical, because you cannot combine "ever since" (which describes something that happened in the past) with "is having" (which describes something happening in the present).

Answer (score 0):

In the sentence

> Ever since Nina moved to Nebraska, she is having a lot of problems with allergies.

**moved** is in the *past* tense and the verb phrase **is having** is in the *present* (progressive) tense.

In a sentence, the tense of each verb or verb phrase must match.  For example,

> Ever since Nina **moved** to Nebraska, she **has had** a lot of problems with allergies.

In this sentence, both *moved* and *has had* are in the past tense.  Now the verb tenses match and the sentence makes sense.